# dynamic in Task.Run

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, async-await

I have a long running task with the same name in unrelated classes. I was trying to have this code in common method using dynamic.
I am getting following error

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException was unhandled by user code
>    Message=Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'

I tried to isolate the code to the following

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MainAsync();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    static async void MainAsync()
    {
        var classA = new ClassA();
        var classB = new ClassB();
        await RunTask1(classA);
        await RunTask1(classB);
        await RunTask(classA);
        await RunTask(classB);
    }
    static async Task RunTask(dynamic val)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => val.CommonLongRunningTask());
    }
    static async Task RunTask1(ClassA val)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => val.CommonLongRunningTask());
    }
    static async Task RunTask1(ClassB val)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => val.CommonLongRunningTask());
    }
}
internal class ClassA
{
    public void CommonLongRunningTask()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Class A CommonLongRunningTask");
    }
}
internal class ClassB
{
    public void CommonLongRunningTask()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Class B CommonLongRunningTask");
    }
}
```

If I pass the object itself (RunTask1) instead of dynamic it works. I am trying to understand what is happening when I am passing in dynamic.

Comment: Don't use `async void` anywhere other than UI event handlers

Comment: `async void` isn't the problem, this is clearly an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>I haven't yet been able to track it back to something in the language, but it appears you can't have an expression lambda with dynamic expression.</strike> **Update: an expression involving a `dynamic` is always of type `dynamic` regardless of whether there's a void method call, see *Language Aspects* update**

A statement lambda works:

```
private static async Task RunTask(dynamic val)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        val.CommonLongRunningTask();
    });
}
```

#### Update:

Effectively what's going on here is when the compiler encounters this:

```
() => val.CommonLongRunningTask()
```

it interprets at it as the equivalent of:

```
() => {return val.CommonLongRunningTask();}
```

...since it doesn't know at *compile-time* that anything you call on `val` doesn't return anything.  At run-time, it encounters the expression `val.CommonLongRunningTask()` which is of type `void` but cannot `return` that value to even the lowest common denominator `object` and thus throws the exception with message `Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'`

You'd have the very same exception if you re-wrote your `RunTask` as follows:

```
    private static async Task RunTask(dynamic val)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            return val.CommonLongRunningTask();
        });
    }
```

#### Language Aspects

After a bit more research/discussion it appears section 7.5.2 of the C# spec details why this is happening.  Essentially anything involving a dynamic is itself a dynamic type (because at compile time the compiler cannot know how things will be bound) and thus it views "val.CommonLongRunningTask()" as something that returns dynamic (and thus has a run-time error when it realizes it's void at run-time).

Comment: yeah, just use brackets. Let lambda as a method not a expression.

Answer (score 1):

Create a interface for your common method:

```
public interface ICommonTask
{
    void CommonLongRunningTask();
}
```

Implement this in both classes and use it instead:

```
static async Task RunTask(ICommonTask val)

class ClassA : ICommonTask

class ClassB : ICommonTask
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that:

```
() => val.CommonLongRunningTask()
```

translates into something:

```
delegate
{
    return val.CommonLongRunningTask();
}
```

Which will fail at run time because the `CommonLongRunningTask` method you're binding to doesn't have a return type.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same problem and in response to the answer from Peter as to *why* it happens, I came up with a solution to get Task.Run from dynamic void method to work regardless.

rewrite:

```
() => val.CommonLongRunningTask()
```

as

```
() => ForceDynamicExpressionBackToVoid(() => val.CommonLongRunningTask())
```

with the following method:

```
private void ForceDynamicExpressionBackToVoid(Action @dynamic)
{
    @dynamic.Invoke();
}
```

The caveat being that you have to know that any CommonLongRunningTask you end up with at runtime is guaranteed to return void, otherwise you'll get another exception.